# How do I prove an equation in partial derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

When x = e^s cost and y = e^s sint how to get the below equation correctly? Everytime I get extra things in my answer. Can someone help me to get the correct answer. 
But I get a different answer. I want to identify the wrong point in my answer.[image: Here is my answer]
[image: this is the thing which I have to show]

Comment: That first picture seems unrelated.

Comment: Sorry I will change that

Comment: I added the correct one

Comment: Please [use latex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than pictures next time :)

Answer (score 0):

I use subscripts for derivatives. Note these identities:
$$
x=x_s, \;\;\;y=y_s,\;\;\; x_t = -y,\;\;\; y_t = x,\;\;\; x^2+y^2=e^{2s}
$$
Then you get:
\begin{align}
u_s &= u_xx_s + u_yy_s\\
u_{ss} 
&= x_s\partial_s u_x + u_x x_{ss} + y_s\partial_s u_y + u_y y_{ss}\\
&= u_{xx}x^2 + u_{xy}xy + u_{x}x + u_{yx}xy + u_{yy}y^2 + u_yy\\
&= u_{xx}x^2 + u_{yy}y^2 + 2u_{yx}xy  + u_yy + u_{x}x\\
u_t
&= u_xx_t+u_yy_t \\ &= -yu_x+u_yx\\
u_{tt} 
&= -y_tu_x-y\partial_tu_x + x_tu_y + x\partial_t u_y\\
&= -xu_x + y^2u_{xx} - 2xyu_{xy} - yu_y-u_{yy}x^2 \\
 u_{tt}+u_{ss} 
&= [y^2+x^2](u_{xx}+u_{yy})- 2xyu_{xy} - yu_y-xu_x+ 2u_{yx}xy  + u_yy + u_{x}x\\
&= e^{2s}(u_{xx}+u_{yy})\\
\therefore\; u_{xx}+u_{yy} &= e^{-2s}( u_{tt} + u_{ss} )
\end{align}